# Unable to read data from S3 in Pyspark on EC2 (standalone setup)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the CSV file (or any file for that matter) from S3 (SSE_KMS encrypted) into pyspark setup locally on EC2 machine. I am getting different type of error with different combination. I am able to download the file using AWS cli shown below:

`aws s3 ls s3://xxxx/ --profile xx`

The above command seems to be working fine. Please see the pyspark code below for which I am getting error (this I am testing in pyspark shell):

```
spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId","XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
df = spark.read.format("csv").load("s3a://bucket/test.csv")
```

The error I am getting below is:

```
21/05/10 04:35:45 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: xxxx, AWS Error Code: InvalidArgument, AWS Error Message: Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4., S3 Extended Request ID: xxx
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.reopen(S3AInputStream.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.openIfNeeded(S3AInputStream.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.read(S3AInputStream.java:156)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:184)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So I assumed this was related to KMS but when I am using the below code:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
spark.conf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
spark.conf.set("fs.s3.session.token","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

spark.sparkContext.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark.conf.set("fs.s3.server-side-encryption-algorithm","SSE-KMS")
spark.conf.set("fs.s3.server-side-encryption.key","value")
df = spark.read.format("csv").load("s3://bucket/test.csv")
```

I am getting the below error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.load.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Service Error Message. -- ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>XXXXXXXXXXX</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>xxx</RequestId><HostId>xxx//xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=</HostId></Error>
```

SPARK VERSION: spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7
The version of external jars (added to $SPARK_HOME/jars) I am using :

```
hadoop-aws-2.7.7.jar
jets3t-0.9.4.jar
spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.1014.jar
```

I have been working on this but could not find the workaround. I know there are many questions in Stack Overflow itself on this subject but none of them have worked for me.

Any help would be really appreciated.

UPDATE:

Below is the policy setup for my bucket

```
{
    "Version": "******",
    "Statement": [
{
            "Sid": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjects"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxx-*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxx-*/*"
            ]
        },
        ]
    }
```

I also tried with the below settings (IAM role based credentials) but got the error.

The code:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.s3.assumed.role.arn", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
spark.read.csv("s3://")
```

The error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, orby setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
```

And if I use `fs.s3` instead of `fs.s3a`. I get below error:

```
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.
: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100M"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned -

1. Double check your AWS access key ID.
2. Check your s3 policy and change, if required.

For reference : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I am accessing using IAM role based credentials. For that I am using the code `spark.conf.set("fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")` but this also not working but i am able to pull data using boto3. For policy, I have updated the question. I havent set the policy but it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this should help, Check this out - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=165286

TLDR:

You might wanna explicitly configure some stuff

1. Set the signature version to v4
2. Set your region explicitly : AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';

   s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

Edit - Tried this, should work too

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=trueenter code here
```

Comment: HI I already tried the above option `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true` but it did not work. I have also updated my question with the S3 policy setup.